# SQL Server: Detect who provoke table trigger to be fired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, ssms

I have a table in SQL Server. This table can be updated and also new rows can be inserted from a .NET application and also directly from SSMS (using T-SQL). So I would like to create a trigger on this table for insert and update and detect what caused the trigger to be fired, either the .NET application or the user currently authenticated in SSMS session. If this possible? If so how?

Comment: You'll need to add further logic to the trigger to store the information in some kind of audit table. You'll likely be looking to use `SYSTEM_USER`, `CURRENT_USER` and `APP_NAME()` (which return the login, user and application names respectively).

Comment: To what end? You can get application names but bear in mind that it's whatever the connection string (chosen by the client) chooses to tell you. So you can use it for information but cannot *trust* it if you're trying to deal with malicious use.

Answer (score 1):

A trigger runs in the user's session so you can look at the session.  But note that the program_name is sent by the client, so a user using SSMS can change it:

```
select program_name, client_interface_name, login_name
from sys.dm_exec_sessions
where session_id = @@spid
```

There's a security feature that allows an application to supply a secret to gain privileges not granted to the connecting user, called [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles)

> An application role is a database principal that enables an
>   application to run with its own, user-like permissions. You can use
>   application roles to enable access to specific data to only those
>   users who connect through a particular application.